# What is the best way to get and compare object identities?

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I want to implement dictionary and set in GJS, but the only comparison operator available for `Object` is `===`, so if I implement them in standard JavaScript they will be slow when `Object`s are used as keys. GJS uses the official standalone SpiderMonkey release (1.8.5) that doesn't have Map and Set yet. What's the best way to get introduce API that will allow to compare object identities?

- I could write a C module for GJS that will allow for getting and comparing object identites

  - Maybe I could use pointers to `JSObject`s.

    - Is it guaranteed that SpiderMonkey won't move `JSObject`s?
    - C standard doesn't allow comparing pointers that aren't from the same block.
    - And new 64-bit computers have 64-bit addresses that don't fit into `double`'s 53 bit integers.
  - I could manually associate objects with numbers.

    - How do I associate arbitrary data with an arbitrary existing `JSObject` without adding properties visible from JavaScript into it?
- Or maybe there's a SpiderMonkey specific extension that will allow me to do it in pure JavaScript without writing C modules?